# How to make \newcommand with one argument that does nothing.

Tags: spacing, macros

I am writing a document with extra notes intended only for myself.

```
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\emph{Note: #1}}
%\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{}
```

When I wish to remove the extra comments, I simply comment the first line and uncomment the latter line. Then each call to `\mycomment` should do nothing. However, instead each call generates a small space. Is it possible to remove this space?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just add `\renewcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\null}` if you want to remove these.

Comment: Perhaps, depending on how you use it, `%\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\unskip}`

Comment: Thank you! `\null` will reduce the space, but there will be a noticeable space after multiple calls. `\unskip` works with the same effect as `\ignorespaces` (no space even after multiple calls).

Comment: re difference between `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip`. The former seems indeed to be safer; In some locations, `\unskip` can generate an "ERROR: You can't use `\unskip` in vertical mode.", but `\ignorespaces` will work fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Safest is probably

```
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\ignorespaces}
```

Comment: Thank you! This creates no space even for multiple calls.

Comment: Note that the command never creates space. The question is about removing space that the author has added to the document. that is with the empty definition in the question,  `xx\mycomment{zz}yy` has no space but if the author adds space `xx \mycomment{zz} yy` then there are two spaces, but this definition makes the second be ignored (`\unskip` as discussed in the comments tries to remove the first but should be guarded by a test that the space is there)