# Include subitem from a file into master file

Tags: input, include, cv

I am currently working on my resume and I am trying to make it modular. 
I have a content folder which has different `.tex` file for each section in resume such as `education.tex`, `experience.tex`, and `projects.tex`. I want to write all the contents in these section files and include selective heading into master file.

For Example: `projects.tex` will have all the projects I have ever done. I want to include the top three relevant in `master.tex` file. How can I do so?

My `master.tex` file should look like:

```
\input{documentSettings}
\input{customCommands}

\begin{document}
    \input{content/00_heading}
    \input{content/01_education}
          \input{edu1}
          \input{edu2}
    \input{content/02_experience}
          \input{exp1}
          \input{exp2}
    \input{content/03_projects}
          \input{proj1}
          \input{proj2}
          \input{proj3}
    \input{content/04_techincal_skills}
\end{document}
```

Please suggest if there is some other better method to make it modular

Comment: Seem a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378607/using-input-to-insert-a-section-of-a-document-into-another, but  I would do is split every item (project, etc.) in a  file, and group items in folders. I case of nested dependencies 
 (items including images of a sub-subfolder, for instance) you can use  [import](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227690/11604).

Comment: @Fran Are you suggesting to make different `.tex` file for all the projects, experiences, etc.? Don't you think it'll be challenging to maintain the documents?

Comment: If you want to be modular, I think that is the simplest way. If you are consistent with directory structure and  file names it  should be easy to maintain, specially if each "module" in only plain text  without any  format  that can change.  In this sense I would take a look at [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/) before to try this directly in LaTeX.

Comment: On the other hand, at least for your  publications will be indeed better manage citations of a bibtex/bilblatex bibliography that make a .tex file for each reference, even using bookdown.