# Centralized Master Equation in Single File like `\cite{}`

Tags: equations, include

Is it possible in latex to have single file like `equations.tex` and able to call part of it to our `main.tex` just like a combination of `\include{}` or `\input{}` and `\cite{}`?

For example I have a centralized equation.tex with content:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:miqp-obj}
\min_{\mathbf{x}}C = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^{T}Q\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{x} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:miqp-cons}
A\mathbf{x} \preceq \mathbf{b},
\end{equation}
```

and in my `main.tex` I call:

```
Equation can be seen in (\ref{eq:miqp-obj}).

\include{equations.tex/eq:miqp-obj}
% or \input{equations.tex/eq:miqp-obj}
```

The idea is to have a centralized equations. A workaround is using `eqautions/` folder and have each equation its separate `.tex` file, then use `\input`.

Comment: Maybe the `catchfilebetweentags` package can be useful, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4952/ and the (rather short) [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.pdf)

Comment: Or maybe [Using \`\input\` to insert a section of a document into another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378607/using-input-to-insert-a-section-of-a-document-into-another) which has also an approach using the [clipboard package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/clipboard/clipboard.pdf).

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I'll try implementing define new comment as the suggested on marked as duplicate (even if it is not complete duplicate, it has very high similarity).