# Error when trying to add Pgfplots to figure environment

Tags: pgfplots, floats, graphs, compilation-error

I am relatively new to LaTeX, but I have been attempting to write my Master's thesis using it. I have been creating several plots using the pgfplots package. However, when I attempt to insert these graphs into the figure environment to reference them and add captions, I encounter an error. Strangely, they work perfectly fine outside this environment. Here's an example of one of the plots:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,fleqn]{repUERJ}
% ---
% Packages
% ---
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{textcomp} %trademark


% ---
% College model
% ---
\usepackage[frame=no,algline=yes,font=default]{repUERJformat}
\usepackage{repUERJpseudocode}
% ---
% Citations packages
% ---
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

%newcommands
\newcommand{\inputgraph}[2]{% #1 = file, #2 = graph name %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378607/using-input-to-insert-a-section-of-a-document-into-another
  \long\def\GRAPH ##1#2 {}%
  \input{#1}
}
\let\ENDGRAPH\endinput

    \begin{document}
         \begin{figure}
               \caption{Caption}
                \label{fig:enter-label}
            \begin{tikzpicture} %Plot
                \begin{axis}[
                title={},
                xlabel={Time (days)},
                ylabel={UFC/g},
                xmin=0, xmax=30,
                legend pos= outer north east,
                legend style={font=\tin},
                grid style=dashed,
            ]

            \addplot[
                color=cyan,
                mark=square,
                error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit
                ]
                coordinates {
                (7,56400) +- (0,90)
                (14,9730) +- (0,90)
                (21,1570) +- (0,70)
                (28,12500) +- (0,90)
                };

            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=square,
                error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit
                ]
                coordinates {
                (7,0)
                (14,0)
                (21,0)
                (28,0)
                };
                \legend{Blank, \ch{H2SO4}}
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As I mentioned, I'm new to LaTeX, so I may not be using the most elegant solutions here. I'm employing various packages to conform the text to the college format. I apologize if it appears somewhat messy.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. There's no way for us to compile your code as-is because we don't have access to your `repUERJ` document class and packages. You also didn't include your error message, so it's hard to tell exactly *what* is going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) for how to write a MWE.

When you write `legend style={font=\tin},`, you probably meant:

```
legend style={font=\tiny},
```