# Export/ Compile latex file without parenthetical references

Tags: macros, bibliographies, citing, spelling, export

I want to run a grammar check on my text and hence need to do away with the parenthetical references. Is there a way in latex wherein we dont export the citations?

Example:

> Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence (AI) has penetrated into
>   many do-mains besides Information technology. AI is now beyond a
>   tooling role and isinfact applied for autonomous operations in domains
>   like Banking- where it is used to determine creditworthiness [1],
>   Medicine - in diagnostics [2], Construction - for Township and
>   building planning [4] ..

Becomes:

> Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence (AI) has penetrated into
>   many domains besides Information technology. AI is now beyond a
>   tooling role and is in fact applied for autonomous operations in domains
>   like Banking- where it is used to determine credit worthiness,
>   Medicine - in diagnostics, Construction - for Township and
>   building planning,

Comment: Hi, welcome. Are the citations generated with \cite?

Comment: When you say export, do you mean compile to PDF/DVI or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes the citations are generated with \cite

Comment: @moewe Yes, I mean outputted to PDF or HTML, anything such.

Comment: Depending on your exact set-up, the packages you use and what exactly you want to remove, `\renewcommand*{\cite}[2][]{}` might be a good first step to remove citations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the commands you use to generate the citations with by doing this just before you start your document:

```
\renewcommand*{\cite}[1]{\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
```

This will cause the commands to produce no output and even remove spaces that were around the citation when needed. ([As suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124590/116425))

If you use other citation commands like `\citeauthor` then you also want to overwrite those:

```
\renewcommand*{\citeauthor}[1]{\ignorespaces}
```

*Note that the number* `[1]` *is the amount of arguments the original command takes.*